# Density function and expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability, expectation, density-function

Random variable $X$ has exponential distribution $\mathcal E(\lambda)$ with probability $0.3$, and distribution given by density function $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x+1|},\forall x\in\mathbb R$ with probability $0.7$. Find density (density function) and expectation of a random variable $X$.

First, I don't understand why are we given probabilities $0.3$ and $0.7$?

Density function of an exponential distribution is given by $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},x\ge 0,\lambda>0$. This is the density function for the first case. Expectation of $X$ for the first case is
$$E(X)=\int_0^{+\infty}x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=-\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

In the second case, we are already given the density function $f_2(x)$.
$$  |x+1| =
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & x+1\ge 0, & x\ge -1\\
-(x+1), & x+1< 0, & x<-1
\end{cases}$$
$$  f_2(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}e^{x+1},  & x<-1 \\
\frac{1}{2}e^{-(x+1)}, & x\ge -1
\end{cases}$$

Now, I am not sure how to set limits of integration for evalution of expectation.
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{1}{2}xe^{x+1}dx+\int_{-1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2}xe^{-(x+1)}dx=-1+0=-1$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is a mixed random variable...

Comment: @PMF, Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: It looks like you have the right work for the expectation in the $f_2$ case. Now you just add $0.3 \lambda + 0.7(-1)$.

Comment: I mean a "mixture" distribution...

Comment: @PMF, Do you mean that my solution is not correct?

Comment: @Mark Fischler, What do you mean by adding $0.3\lambda +0.7(-1)$? Do you think that my solution in the first case is wrong?

Comment: @user300047 - You need to have your $\lambda$ inverted...see below...

Comment: @PMF, Are you planning to answer? What do you mean by inverted $\lambda$? Do you mean instead of $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, we need $f(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}$?

Comment: No, I mean instead of $0.3\lambda$ in your answer above, it needs to be $\frac{0.3}{\lambda}$ ...does that make sense? See my answer below...that should make sense.

Comment: @PMF, Did you post an answer?

Comment: Yes, I posted it below - You may need to refresh your browser...

Comment: @PMF, Could you point out what are correct solutions and give detailed procedure of it (if my solutions are not correct)?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. I already posted a solution below.

Comment: Yes, of course it was supposed to be $0.3/\lambda$ not $0.3\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mixture distribution (If I'm understanding your question correctly).

$$f_1(x) = \lambda  e^{-\lambda  x}$$

and

$$f_2(x) = \frac{e^{-\left| x+1\right| }}{2}$$.

Then, the density function is

$$g(x) = 0.3 f_1(x) + 0.7 f_2(x) = 0.3 \lambda  e^{-\lambda  x} + 0.7\frac{e^{-\left| x+1\right| }}{2}$$.

To calculate $E(X)$, we follow first principles noting the respective domains of support, so we get:

$$E(X) = 0.3 \int_0^{\infty}x\lambda  e^{-\lambda x} + 0.7 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{e^{-\left| x+1\right| }}{2}=\frac{0.3}{\lambda }-0.7$$

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear.

Comment: In the last integral, you have forgotten to multiply the function with $x$.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.